# Two steps analysis in Google Earth Engine at pixel level

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I would like to make an analysis with GEE that consists of two steps:

1. From an Image Collection of 12 images, where each image is the precipitation for each month, extract for each pixel the wettest month (i.e., the image where the value of precipitation is maximum). Each pixel may have a different value, since the wettest month may be June in some places and October in others.
2. Once the wettest month is extracted for each pixel, extract the maximum temperature in that pixel for the wettest month. The maximum temperature can be extracted from an other Image Collection with 12 images, where each image is the maximum temperature for each month.

Therefore, I firstly need to know the wettest month in each pixel to then extract the maximum temperature in that pixel for that wettest month. I do not really know how to do it in GEE, or if it is even possible. I know how to do it from a matrix/array point of view, thinking of pixels, but it is differente with GEE. I transformed an Image Collection to an Array, having the wettest month as a value of the resulting array, but I do not know how to follow to extract the maximum temperature using that value.

**SOLUTION**

I update this question with the solution proposed by Noel Gorelick, that worked for me:

```
var filter = ee.Filter.equals({
  leftField: 'month',
  rightField: 'month'
})

var simpleJoin = ee.Join.inner();

var innerJoin = ee.ImageCollection(simpleJoin.apply(prec_imc,tmax_imc,filter))

var joined = innerJoin.map(function(feature) {
  return ee.Image.cat(feature.get('primary'), feature.get('secondary'));
})

print('Joined', joined)

var maxImage = joined.reduce(ee.Reducer.max(2)) 

print(maxImage)

Map.addLayer(maxImage.select('max1'),{min:0,max:30,palette:['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','purple']},'Maximum temperature of the wettest month')
```

Comment: A solution should be posted as a solution, not inside the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two image collections (either with a join on month or just a for loop using addBands if there are only 12) into a single 12-image collection with 2 bands in each image (precip first), and apply a `ee.Reducer.max` reducer using the `numInputs` option to carry along the temperature that goes with the max precipitation.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I am going to update the question the solution.